# Equation 60 divide by 2

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

This puzzle is from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFBqdanxyXM&list=PLwaeDTM5Iql4QGc0vjYwWbL7muoMYpN-U)

> 60 / 2(10+5) = ?

The answer mentioned is 450. The same answer is shown by Google. But, I believe the answer is 2.

Is the answer 2 or 450?

Comment: This is not really a puzzle. Also the answer is 450 as you do division first. If you had 60/(2*(10+5)) then it would be 2.

Comment: 2(15) won't get executed first?

Comment: So, you have accepted an answer that is the replica of the video you link to in your question (except that the video explains why the division is executed before the multiplication, which the accepted answer doesn't). I really don't see the point of your question.

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer. The way you wrote it has no space between the "2" and the bracket, and spaces around the "/". This clearly indicates that the "2(10+5)" should be evaluated first. And there are many old mathematics writings that use this convention because it was troublesome to typeset fractional expressions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

60 / 2(10+5)

= 60/2(15)

= 30(15)

= 450